# Difference between formname.show and load formname

Tags: excel, vba

Will you please explain with is the difference between the below mentioned statements in excel vba

Form_name.show

Load Form_name

thanks & regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form_name.show` It will simply show your form

`Load Form_name`. It will load item when form opens and it will load forms

Unlike the Show method which cares of both loading and displaying the Form, the load statement doesn't show the Form. You have to call the Form's Show method to display it on the desktop.

[**SOURCE**](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/lesson14.html)